# How to compile with C# Wrapper of OpenSSL 3.0

Tags: openssl, openssl-net

We are upgrading from openssl 1.0.2 to 3.0.1. With openssl 1.0.2, we were using this wrapper -  https://github.com/openssl-net/openssl-net/blob/master/ManagedOpenSsl/Core/Native.cs

Any idea from where to get the latest C# wrapper for openssl 3.0

Searched on internet, not able to find any C# wrapper for 3.0.1